# Python - Benchmarking with Airspeed Velocity - Apparent Quantisation of Timings

Tags: python, benchmarking, scikit-image

I am using Airspeed Velocity to benchmark some speedups to part of `scikit-image`. The results appear to contain several repeated values, and values which are near integer multiples of each other:

```
--                                symmetric / normed
------------ -----------------------------------------------------------
   shape      True / True   True / False   False / True   False / False
============ ============= ============== ============== ===============
  (50, 50)      3.12±0ms     1.56±0.6ms      3.12±2ms        1.30±0ms
 (100, 100)     5.21±0ms      1.95±0ms       3.91±0ms        1.56±0ms
 (200, 200)     7.81±0ms      3.12±0ms       7.81±0ms        3.12±2ms
============ ============= ============== ============== ===============
```

This points to an apparent quantisation of the output times, i.e. I am approaching the limit of the time resolution. Is there any way I can get around this, e.g. by forcing more runs to be performed?

My command line was `asv run -E existing -b time_greycomatrix`.

Comment: That's a fantastic name for a benchmarking / profiling tool.  Never heard of it before, unfortunately, but that name is right up there with Linux's hardware error-detection and correction / logging tools  (like ECC RAM) formerly being hosted on https://ButterSideUp.com/

Comment: Thanks for working on improving scikit-image!  This is the kind of question you can also direct to our mailing list, where more developer eyes may see it.

Comment: Thanks @StefanvanderWalt.

Comment: Can you produce a minimum example (including cloning a specific commit from scikit-image)? It's very weird. If I can reproduce on my machine, I'd suggest raising an issue on the asv repo.

Comment: Also, it looks like there was new release of asv just a couple of weeks ago. Do you have the latest version?

Comment: Yes, I'm on asv version 0.3. I'll look at producing a minimal example.